# What is gitc filesystem from repo's source code?

Tags: git, repo

I used basic repo commands to download Android sources. Then decided to browse
the source code of repo. Things looked straightforward but there are few things
that I didn't find explanation for and Google search didn't help.

What does gitc-init command do?

**I used repo init so what it is the difference between
repo init and repo gitc-init**

In the source of repo the function

```
def gitc_parse_clientdir(gitc_fs_path):
  """Parse a path in the GITC FS and return its client name.

  Args:
    gitc_fs_path: A subdirectory path within the GITC_FS_ROOT_DIR.

  Returns:
    The GITC client name.
  """
```

What are the gitc clients to use?

In the _Init function

```
  try:
    if gitc_init:
      gitc_manifest_dir = get_gitc_manifest_dir()
      if not gitc_manifest_dir:
        print('fatal: GITC filesystem is not available. Exiting...',
              file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

**What is ia GITC filesystem? Is it available on Linux?**

Comment: Seems like a google internal tool to manage android source.

Answer (score 0):

gitc logic is only usable by internal Google employees which is why it isn't displayed in any normal output.  It's also deprecated and not really supported, so hopefully we'll delete it someday.